# Not able to fetch config with spring cloud server

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I get an empty response when I fetch config with URL

e.g :- http://localhost:8888/emi-app/dev

Response:-

```
{
    "name": "emi-app",
    "profiles": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": []
}
```

Need to know the reason why I am getting empty response

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `emi-app-dev.properties` or `emi-app-dev.yml` is present in the Git config repo. Also make sure it's added committed.

Comment: The git folder structure is like -Gitproject -server-config  <I have this project path for git repository > also defined property -  (spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=config/ )                                                                           
<Project>server-config has folders                                                                      
server- this is my server which is reading config                                                                                                               
config- all 5 config files reside here

Comment: application.yml ---              
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native

 debug=true
 spring.cloud.config.label=Cloud_Config ----my branch name in git
 spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=
 https://gitlab.@@@@@@.com/emiapp/server-config.git
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=config/
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=XXXXXX
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=XXXXXXX@123
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.skipSslValidation: true
    management.security.enabled=false

Comment: First, could you change the format of your parameters in application.yml to YAML format? Or use the .properties extension instead of .yml